# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (131022120001Z) but the values comes from openssl_x509_parse()

Tags: php, datetime, openssl, x509

I'm using `openssl_x509_parse()` to parse a digital certificate.

I've written an entity class that reads the array and transforms the values in objects.

So, for dates I use `\DateTime()`.

The problem is that sometimes the object creation doesn't fail and sometimes it does.

So, for example, if I get the digital certificate of Google.com, I get as result the following array:

```
...
"validFrom" => "151118151813Z"
"validTo" => "160216000000Z"
"validFrom_time_t" => 1447859893
"validTo_time_t" => 1455580800
...
```

Those strings cause an error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1474632000) at
>   position 8 (0): Unexpected character

I don't understand how to transform them into a `DateTime` object. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$dto = new DateTime('@'.'1447859893');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String `151118151813Z` is datetime represented as `ymdHis` in Zulu timezone, which you can parse as:

```php
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHise', '151118151813Z');
echo $dt->format('c');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/479885)</kbd>

Or just use unix timestamp format `1447859893`:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('@1447859893');
echo $dt->format('c');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/479883)</kbd>

In both examples you get same output.

Comment: Why is used the Zulu timezone? Is there a reason? The value is returned from a parsing of a x509 certificate: does this matter?

Comment: @Aerendir: timezone must be known. It kinda doesn't matter in which timezone datetime is presented, but practice is to set in UTC +00:00, which iz Zulu. You can then convert it to any timezone you wish...

Comment: How can I create a `DateTime` in the Zulu timezone? Because if I use `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()`(http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php) I can't find the Zulu timezone. As I need to do a comparison between the dates get from the digital certificate with the current time (to know if the certificate is valid and is not expired) I'd like to better understand if I'm safe doing something like `new \DateTime() > $certificateFrom` (where `$certificateFrom` is in the Zulu timezone and `\DateTime()`isn't).

Comment: @Aerendir: no need to create DateTime object with Zulu timezone, because you can compare DateTime object in different timezones. Based on that, `new \DateTime > $certificateFrom` **will** work.